# Joining GUI (Swing) and Business logic

Tags: java, swing, observer-pattern, business-logic

DISCLAIMER:- The following example is highly scaled downed version of what I am trying to do in reality.

**Overview:**

•   **Application name:** Random number generator.

•   **Desired application flow:** The RandomNumberLogic class generates a random number every 10 seconds. This generated number should be displayed on the RandomNumberPanel.

•   **Application design goal:** Keep the GUI and the business logic as separate as possible.
(low coupling is the word I am looking for, I guess).

•   **Code:**

**BasicRandomApplication.java**

```
package SideActivities;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BasicRandomApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
           public void run()
           {
                new MainFrame();
                RandomNumberLogic x = new RandomNumberLogic();
                x.generateNumbers();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.java**

```
package SideActivities;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
    RandomNumberPanel randomNumberPanel;

    MainFrame()
    { 
        randomNumberPanel = new RandomNumberPanel();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(randomNumberPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

**RandomNumberLogic.java**

```
package SideActivities;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumberLogic
{
    private ModelListener listener;

    public void generateNumbers()
    {
        long firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int refreshRate = 10 * 1000;
        long delta = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            long secondTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            delta += (secondTime - firstTime) / refreshRate;
            if (delta >= 1)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                ModelEvent e = new ModelEvent();
                e.setNumber(random.nextInt());
                listener.refreshData(e);
                delta--;
           }
       }
   }

   public void setListener(ModelListener listener)
   {
        this.listener = listener;
   }
}
```

**RandomNumberPanel.java**

```
package SideActivities;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RandomNumberPanel extends JPanel implements ModelListener
{
    private JLabel number;

    RandomNumberPanel()
    {
        number = new JLabel();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(number, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3));
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshData(ModelEvent e)
    {
        number.setText(e.getNumber() + "");
    }

}
```

**ModelEvent.java**

```
package SideActivities;

public class ModelEvent
{
    private int number;

    public void setNumber(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

**ModelListener.java**

```
 package SideActivities;

 public interface ModelListener
 {
     public void refreshData(ModelEvent e);
 }
```

Question 1) Why does my GUI application take forever to start showing something?

Question 2) Why do I get the following exception?

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SideActivities.RandomNumberLogic.generateNumbers(RandomNumberLogic.java:23)
    at SideActivities.BasicRandomApplication$1.run(BasicRandomApplication.java:15)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

***Solution to Q2) The setListener method was never called.***

I made the following changes, and still the GUI takes forever to update. What could be the reason? Am i building the application right ?

**BasicRandomApplication.java**

```
package SideActivities;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BasicRandomApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                MainFrame y = new MainFrame();
                RandomNumberLogic x = new RandomNumberLogic();
                x.setListener(y.randomNumberPanel);
                x.generateNumbers();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: make a check if **private ModelListener listener;** is **NULL** ??

Comment: You are indeed never even setting the listener. You need to somehow link your components together, either by creating a forced lifecycle --- creating one component before the other and then passing it's reference to the other, or by actually using the setListener() method in a controlling method, like your main() for example, where you still have a reference to all relevant objects.

Comment: There is connection between your GUI and the generator (although you have provided an observer pattern for one), so even if you over came the NPE, it's unlikely the UI would be updated.

Comment: So, what should be my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here `listener` is null. Call the method `setListener()` of the class `RandomNumberLogic`